# Import documents from Oracle to SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, import, oracle

I want to know that how can I import my documents from an Oracle database to my SharePoint document library.

I have more than 50,000 documents stored in Oracle database and want to get them in my SharePoint Document Management System.

How can I achieve that? Is there any out-of-the-box way for this?

I searched and implement a few solution and third party tools as well but they only provide a facility to get data in to a SharePoint List, where as I want it to get in my document library?

Please Help.

thank you.

Comment: did you check this: http://www.spmarketplace.com/smart-import.html

Comment: No i didn't. But isn't there any Out of the box solution?  Or any solution without third party?  As the third parties might not be a good option in my scenario.